# Custom sort (usort) on WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, usort

Brief explanation of the environment:

On my website, posts should be sorted according to certain criteria. The website is translated into different languages.
First the posts should be sorted by publication date. The date is stored in the meta field 'publication_date'.
A post has the meta value 'premium'. If it is true, it will be set above posts where 'premium' is false, regardless of its publication date. So premium posts should be always on top and also sorted by date.
Additionally, the meta value 'premium' is only taken into account if you are on the correct language version of the website. This depends on the meta value 'domain'. This is a select field where multiple values are possible.
For example, if I am on the Spanish version of the website, all posts where 'Spain' is included in the meta value 'domain' and the meta value 'premium' is true should be displayed at the top.

For the query I use the Search & Filter Pro plugin ([documentation](https://searchandfilter.com/documentation/)). It already takes care of the sorting by date.

This is what my query looks like:

```
$args = array(
    'search_filter_id' => $searchandfilter_id,
);
$ads_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// premium sort
usort( $ads_query->posts, 'premium_sort' );

/* the loop */
```

And this is my premium sort function so far: (the function `check_main_and_additional_domains()` returns true if the current language of the website matches the 'domain' meta field, otherwise false)

```
function premium_sort( $a, $b ) {
    $a_premium = get_post_meta( $a->ID, 'premium', true );
    $b_premium = get_post_meta( $b->ID, 'premium', true );

    if ( check_main_and_additional_domains( $a->ID ) && check_main_and_additional_domains( $b->ID ) ) {
        if ( $a_premium && $b_premium ) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ( ! $a_premium && ! $b_premium ) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ( ! $a_premium && $b_premium ) {
            return 1;
        }
        if ( $a_premium && ! $b_premium ) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if ( ! check_main_and_additional_domains( $a->ID ) && ! check_main_and_additional_domains( $b->ID ) ) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ( ! check_main_and_additional_domains( $a->ID ) && check_main_and_additional_domains( $b->ID ) ) {
        if ( $b_premium ) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if ( check_main_and_additional_domains( $a->ID ) && ! check_main_and_additional_domains( $b->ID ) ) {
        if ( $a_premium ) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble getting the sorting right. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I am not an PHP expert so please don't be too harsh. I would be very grateful for your help and constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the logic being inconsistent.

```
if (!check_main_and_additional_domains($a->ID) && check_main_and_additional_domains($b->ID)) {
    if ($b_premium) {
        return 1;
    }
}

if (check_main_and_additional_domains($a->ID) && !check_main_and_additional_domains($b->ID)) {
    if ($a_premium) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Judging by the section right above that, where for `$a_premium && ! $b_premium` you're returning -1, I think what you need to try is change the `if ($a_premium) {` to also return -1 instead of 1.

Comment: That's right! Now that you point it out, it's all clear. I was apparently too focused on the output of true or false instead of paying attention to the fact that I have to return 1, -1 or 0